# How to Copy a String Array to Another String Array Using C#?

Tags: c#, copy, arrays

I have two String Arrays named as `items` and `items1`
`items` array consists of 1296 elements
`items1` array consists of 8 elements
copy `items1` into `items`. i tried something like this but it doesn't work, let check this out

```
 items1.CopyTo(items, items1.Length -1);
 Array.Copy(items1, items, items1.Length-1);
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?

Comment: Where you want to copy those elements? You want `items` to have *first* 8 elements from `items1`, or it should be *last* 8 elements? Or you want `items` to contain 8 elements only?

Comment: which version of .net framework

Comment: Have you checked this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx - What is the exact problem? How many elements do you want to copy?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky items1 consists of 8 elements. and items consists of 1296 elements

Comment: @Anjali I know that, please read my questions carefully

Comment: @lazyberezovsky copy all the 8 elements into items array

Comment: @Anjali  copy all the 8 elements is fine. but starting from which position? 0 or last or what?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Last

Comment: @Anjali...understand this simply your first array have 1296 elements and second array have 8 elements ..now it is but obvious that you cannot copy 1296 elements into 8 elements because size is different else you will get `array index out of bound error` so from 1296 element you have to choose 8 elements(as that is the size of destination array) ..now you have to tell us where should this 8 elements come from (start,middle ,end)..

Comment: @Kyle these 8 elements are different.so we want to increase the size of first array to 1234

Comment: @Anjali Then you want to append or concatenate rather than copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Array.Resize(ref items, items.Length + items1.Length);
Array.Copy(items1, 0, items, items.Length - items1.Length, items1.Length);
```

If you want elements to be appended rather than overwritten try the following

```
items = items.Concat(items1).ToArray();
```

Btw use meaningful names, `items` and `items1` doesn't makes any sense

Answer (score 1):

use Linq's Concat method

```
items.Concat(items1)
```

this will concatenate two arrays together and adding items1 at the end of items , i hope you want items array like that only.

Comment: care to include System.Linq namespace

Comment: i am using Linq namespace. my framework is .net3.5

Comment: @Anjali : See the post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you :

```
var items = new string[]{"A"};
var items1 = new string[] { "B" };
var res = new List<string>();
res.AddRange(items);
res.AddRange(items1);
items = res.ToArray();
```

The main problem in your case was increasing the items array length at run time. If you had sufficient length in items array then you could use:

```
Array.Copy(items1, 0, items, items.Length, items1.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an simple example for copying an `string Array`.

```
     string[] SourceArray= { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S" };

        string[] DestArray= new string[8];
        Array.Copy(SourceArray, 11, DestArray, 0, 8);
```

`SourceArray`=Input Array

`11`=starting index (From where the copy should start in source array)

`DestArray`=Is your array in which the elements have to be copied

`0`=Starting index of Destination Array

`8`=Number of elemets to be copied in the array

**Output:**

{L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S}

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Array.Resize(ref items, items.Length + items1.Length);
Array.Copy(items1, 0, items, items.Length-items1.Length, items1.Length);
```

It resizes the destination array, `items`, to be large enough for both arrays.
Then it copies the source array, `items1`, to the newly-added space at the end of the destination array.